# Why is std::function empty when it's captured by a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

I'm working on a thread pool. I have the following function that dispatches work to the threads.

```
void dispatch(const std::function<void(void)>& work, Priority priority = Priority::Default, bool loop = false);
```

It would be nice to easily get results back so I've written this function:

```
template<typename T>
Future<T> dispatchFuture(const std::function<T(void)>& work, Priority priority = Priority::Default) {
    Future<T> future;

    std::cout << !!work << std::endl;
    this->dispatch([work, future]() mutable {
        std::cout << !!work << std::endl;
        future.setValue(work());
    }, priority, false);

    return future;
}
```

However, the dispatched lambda throws a `std::bad_function_call` exception when it's executed. The `cout` statements show that `work` contains a valid target in the `dispatchFuture` call, but not inside the lambda.

This is how `dispatchFuture` is called

```
threadPool.dispatchFuture<int>([]() {
    std::cout << "I'm a work item producing results" << std::endl;
    return 4 + 5;
});
```

Comment: What does a copy-constructor of `Future` look like? You have at least three copies in play here: the local variable `future`, the capture inside the lambda, and the return value of `dispatchFuture`. Would a `setValue` call on the second affect the third?

Comment: Does `dispatch` store a reference to its `work` parameter, by any chance? You are passing a temporary to it: I wonder if it somehow ends up with a reference to that temporary, which becomes dangling when that temporary is destroyed. All in all, it would be best if you show a [mcve].

Comment: Show how you call `dispatchFuture`.  It could be that you are storing a copy of something that holds a reference that has gone out of scope.

Comment: `dispatch` doesn't store a reference to `work`, it stores it by value in an std::queue. The `work` passed to `dispatch` is invoked without a problem, it's the captured std::function in the lambda generated by dispatchFuture that throws the exception.

Comment: I've added how I'm calling dispatchFuture.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].